# Excel Dependent Data Validation

Tags: excel, validation

I have a list of Locations and respective Products as below:

```
+----------+---------+
| Location | Product |
+----------+---------+
| London   | A       |
| London   | B       |
| London   | C       |
| New York | D       |
| New York | E       |
| New York | B       |
| Tokyo    | F       |
| Tokyo    | G       |
| Tokyo    | E       |
| Sydney   | H       |
| Sydney   | I       |
| Sydney   | F       |
| Dubai    | J       |
| Dubai    | K       |
| Dubai    | L       |
+----------+---------+
```

In another sheet, I want a data validation where if user has selected location `London` in say column `A` then the Column `B` validation should only show me the list with Products `A`, `B` & `C`.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Thanks MarianD for editing the question!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution.

Locations in A column with Header Name as RegionStart and Location Column(including header) named as RegionColumn
Products in B column with Products Column named as CustColumn
Another Column in D with all available Locations with Column Header as Regions and list of REgions(excluding header) named as RegionList

Now in another sheet(where I need the drop-downs), 
For Locations List - Source Formula for List as below - 
=IF(C2="",RegionList,B2)

For Products List - Source Formula for List as below - 
=OFFSET(RegionStart, MATCH(B2, RegionColumn, 0) -1, 1, COUNTIF(RegionColumn,B2), 1)

Upon selecting London in Locations list, the Products list shows only A,B,C

Comment: [Contextures.com](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) has a good example of dependent drop-down lists.  Looks similar to what you've done above.